# How do I get the values from key value pairs of a js-object to show it in a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

```
[
  {
    "business_code": "U001",
    "cust_number": 200769623,
    "clear_date": "2020-02-11",
    "buisness_year": "2020-01-01",
    "doc_id": "1930438491",
    "posting_date": "2020-01-26",
    "document_create_date": "2020-01-25",
    "document_create_date1": "2020-01-26",
    "due_in_date": "2020-02-10",
    "invoice_currency": "USD",
    "document_type": "RV",
    "posting_id": 1,
    "area_business": "",
    "total_open_amount": 54273.28,
    "baseline_create_date": "2020-01-26",
    "cust_payment_terms": "NAH4",
    "invoice_id": 1930438491,
    "isOpen": 0,
    "aging_bucket": null,
    "is_deleted": 0
  },
  {
    "business_code": "U001",
    "cust_number": 200980828,
    "clear_date": "2019-08-08",
    "buisness_year": "2019-01-01",
    "doc_id": "1929646410",
    "posting_date": "2019-07-22",
    "document_create_date": "2019-07-22",
    "document_create_date1": "2019-07-22",
    "due_in_date": "2019-08-11",
    "invoice_currency": "USD",
    "document_type": "RV",
    "posting_id": 1,
    "area_business": "",
    "total_open_amount": 79656.6,
    "baseline_create_date": "2019-07-22",
    "cust_payment_terms": "NAD1",
    "invoice_id": 1929646410,
    "isOpen": 0,
    "aging_bucket": null,
    "is_deleted": 0
  }]
```

I have a js object like this stored in variable 'data' and I want to show it in a table in react and currently, I am doing this.

```
export default function DataLoading() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({}); .
  useEffect(async () => {
    setData(await getData());
    console.log(data);
  }, []);

  const headers = Object.keys(data[0]); //ERROR
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {headers.map((header) => (
              <th>{header}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {data.map((user) => (  //ERROR
          <tr>
            {headers.map((header) => (
              <td>{user[header]}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
}
```

I want to make the keys business_code as the table heading and its value as the table body entry.

```
Object.keys(data[0]);
```

is giving an error : `DataLoading.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`
This error goes away if I remove {} from useState({}).

```
<tbody>
        {data.map((user) => (
          <tr>
            {keys.map((header) => (
              <td>{user[header]}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
</tbody>
```

This code is giving an error: `DataLoading.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function`

My object 'data' looks like this ..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First off, the default value you provide the `useState` should be an array not an object. The error you are getting for `const headers = Object.keys(data[0]);` is probably because you used an object as default value. After changing the default value, see if the `data` is being properly set inside the `useEffect` and the `getData` method is actually returning something.

Comment: still, it is showing the same error.

Comment: Did you check if the `getData` method is returning something ? 
Which error is it showing ?